# Bash script for iterating through defined set of file names and performing commands

Tags: svn, bash, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a set of folders named for example 10, 12, 13, 14, 18, 24 etc. They don't change numbers in any standard increment. I then need to move repetitively into the folders and then into the next one to perform SVN commands which are the same except for some variable extension, e.g.:

```
/home/boy$ cp /home/files/*Session10.* . ; svn add *Session10.*; svn commit; cd ..; cd 12;
```

Then the next command is analogous:

```
/home/boy$ cp /home/files/*Session12.* . ; svn add *Session12.*; svn commit; cd ..; cd 14;
```

So there should be an array or list defined, and then a for loop through that list, and then a variable whose name is expanded to be fed into the cp and svn command.
Any thoughts? I hope that it can be done in the command prompt rather than in a bash script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is predefined and you're not iterating over every directory that exists (in other words, if a directory named 99 exists but it's not in your list you want to exclude it), you can iterate over the list:

```
list="10 12 13 14 18 24"; for dir in $list; do cd "$dir"; do_something "foo $dir bar"; done
```

or an array:

```
array=(10 12 13 14 18 24); for idx in ${!array[@]}; do cd "${array[idx]}"; do_something "foo ${array[idx]} bar"; done
```

You can do previous or next array elements like this: `${array[idx-1]}` or `${array[idx+1]}` if you do appropriate checks to make sure you're not trying to retrieve an element with a negative index (an index beyond the last element will return a null).

or:

```
array=(10 12 13 14 18 24); for dir in ${array[@]}; do cd "$dir"; do_something "foo $dir bar"; done
```

which is essentially the same as the list example above.

Answer (score 2):

The no brainer way is:

```
for dir in [0-9][0-9]/; do
    cd "$dir"
    cp /home/files/*Session${dir%/}.* .
    svn add *Session${dir%/}.*
    svn commit
    cd ..
done
```

This will *only* iterate over directories which are composed of 2 digits.

Answer (score 1):

`base=$PWD; for num in *; do cd $base/$num; cp /home/files/*Session${num}.* .; svn add *Session${num}.*; svn commit; done`

Comment: and what is PWD? is this an array set up sometime earlier? and in "for num in *" is the asterix automatically addressing the set of extension names? thanks

Comment: @Vass `$PWD` is "present working directory". It's automatically set by bash. The first `*` is the pattern to match your folders. You may need to replace it with something more specific like `[0-9][0-9]` or `[0-9]*[0-9]`.

Comment: `*` will match both files *and* directories.  This is why I used `[0-9][0-9]/` to glob match only directories.  Of course, then you need to remove the trailing `\\` in the var name which I did with Parameter Expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Time for the find-based solution.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-extended -type d -regex '.*/[0-9]{2}$' -exec \
    bash -c 'dir=${1##*/}
    cd $1 
    cp /home/files/*Session{$dir}.* . 
    svn add *Session${dir}.* 
    svn commit'  -- {} \;
```

EDIT: now more findy than ever.